# Is there any way we can optimize multiple buttons and their onClick methods?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-button

I have an 8 X 7 Tablelayout with 56 buttons. Depending on the index of button clicked the score increases. I have written the code with 56 onClick methods.

**XML Layout**

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:onClick="btn1Click"  />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="btn2Click"  /> 
.
.
.

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button56"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="btn56Click"  />
```

**Java Code:**

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
.
.
Button button56 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button56);

public void btn1Click(android.view.View view) {
   //do Something
}

public void btn2Click(android.view.View view) {
   //sameLines of Code as btn1Click with index = 2;
}
.
.
public void btn56Click(android.view.View view) {
   //sameLines of Code as btn1Click with index = 3;
}
```

**Is there any way I can optimize the code, so that the code is easily maintained and I don't have to write the 64 onClick methods for the other layout again and again!!**

Comment: Is it not painfully obvious that you can reference the same `onClick` method from multiple buttons?

Comment: The score changes with the index of the button pressed, that's why I cannot use the same onClick

Comment: Then each of those 56 methods should be one line: `doSomething(1)` ... ` doSomething(2)`. A better option would be to consider programmatically creating the buttons.

Comment: I'm very curious why you are doing this with an xml. I think it can be better done by adding a button by code, and having the buttons inside a ArrayList. By this, you can init and assign a button and a click listener on a single loop, and can know which button you are handling by the button's position inside the list.

Comment: I tried it using GridLayoutManager and GridView, but there were many constraints like layout, border, padding, color, style, etc.which were not coming as expected. So, I took the pain of writing it through xml layout. Now, I have finished the app, will be releasing it on playstore.

Thanks a lot for your huge time saving help. @March3April4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think doing this inside your code should be better off.

```
final List<Button> mButtons = new ArrayList<>();


void onCreate(){

    for ( int i = 0 ; i< BUTTON_COUNT; i++){

         final Button btn = new Button(mContext);
         btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

              void onClick(View view){
                   int position = mButtons.indexOf(btn); 
                   //since you know the button position, do whatever you want with it.
              }

         });
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement onClickListener on your activity.

For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
                    .
                    .
        Button button56 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button56);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);      
                    .
                    .
        button56.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                break;
                  .
                  .
                  .
            case R.id.button56:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use recyclerview.

its is easy to get the button position and easy to increase or decrease the views

Reference

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/